# What are the markings on the Grouse Grind?

Tags: hiking, canada

I did the Grouse Grind in Vancouver, B.C., this past weekend and there were two markings on the trail.

Ones that went in 1/40ths (more or less):

> 1/40, 3/40, ... 39/40

and larger signs every quarter *something*.

I figure one is elevation and one is distance along the trail, but which one is which?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trail is divided in quarters marked by signs (still more about elevation than actual distance) and the elevation is signed in 40s increments